# Will SerialPort.ReadExisting() Count "/r/n"?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've got a bit of code in a class I'm working on and I've not gotten a chance to test it yet. Here's the code:

```
this.serialPort.Write(serialCommand);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
if (this.serialPort.ReadExisting().EndsWith(">"))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Here's what the string I'm looking for should look like:

```
"Some Returned Data\r\n16 >\r\n"
```

Which visually looks like this:

```
"Some Returned Data  
 16 >"
```

If I use ReadLine() it doesn't count line feeds and carriage returns. I'd use ReadLine(), but I've ran into issues in the past. My normal method of reading the data was to set the NewLine token to `>` as that's the return token signifying the device is finished issuing the command and writing to the buffer.

Will the `EndsWith(">")` work here? Or will it fail because the string technically ends with `">\r\n"`

Comment: Expecting your reads to line up with data boundaries is a bad idea.  Just buffer it up until it contains the string `">\r\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is "\r\n" at the end of the message in buffer when ReadExisting is called, the returned data should contain it, and it should be "Some Returned Data\r\n16 >\r\n".

You can do

```
if(returnedSrting.Trim().EndsWith(">")){...}
```

Although you should be wary of CurrentCulture set for your app when you're using ReadExisting and other string method (e.g. Trim, EndsWith and other that compare strings).

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/2333wewz.aspx)

> As explained in Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET
>   Framework, we recommend that you avoid calling string comparison
>   methods that substitute default values and instead call methods that
>   require parameters to be explicitly specified.

Sometimes they do things with your text data that you never intended to do (especially if you had some characters in your data that fall outside of ASCII printable characters).

```
int byteCount = serialPort.BytesToRead; 
byte[] buffer = new byte[byteCount];
serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, byteCount);
```

This way you always have the real, not modified data and you can convert it yourself later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
str.Trim().EndsWith(">");
```

or

```
str.EndsWith(">\r\n");
```